# Database query node in knime

Tags: database, knime

I was Struggling with the node **"Database Query".**
It shows the default Query as **"SELECT * FROM #table# "**

While entering the query it shows the error as "Invalid Settings" Database view place holder **#table# must not be replaced.**

What actually **#table#** represent?

How does the Database Query node execute?

Can anyone repond, please.

Answer (score 2):

**#table#** represents the table in the incoming database connection port.  The node wraps this incoming connection as a sub query, so for example if you have a connection to a table called 'Names' with a column 'Surname', a column 'Forename' and a column 'Age', and you have previously used a database row filter node to filter by Surname='Smith' then the incoming connection will look something like:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Names) table_1234567890 WHERE "Surname"='Smith'`

If you want to then use the Database Query Node to search for all people John Smith, aged 30 - 45, then in the node dialog you set

`SELECT * FROM #table#
WHERE Forename='John' AND Age BETWEEN 30 AND 45`

Now, if you look at the output port, on the 'Connection' tab, the SQL will look something like:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Names) table_1234567890 WHERE "Surname"='Smith') WHERE Forename='John' AND Age BETWEEN 30 AND 45`